# C# Create a thread in a different context

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

Currently, I'm developing a dll which is an extension of a software.
The software also have an API.

In my extension, when I update the database directly, the new datas are not used because the software should have a cache.

So I've tried to use the API to delegate the updating to the software.
Since I'm in a certain context, I can't connect me to the software even if I use another thread.

I would like to create another process such as a fork to achieve successfully the updating.

What are the ways ?

- create another process that I will call
- ...

Thank you for your suggests ?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, and are you sure that there is a limitation in the API and not in the way you use it?

Comment: If I use a third part program that it uses the API, the connection to the software is good.

Comment: But not into my dll, where I use the same way for the connection. So the only thing I can imagin is from the dll create an independant process to emulate a client connection

Comment: Then my suggestion is first create a console app to test your hypotesis, if it works then you'll have to decide how to call it

Comment: What are the possibilities to call the console app ?

Comment: First write it, then it all depends on how often you have to use it, how many parameters you have... `Process.Start` can execute a program.